# Rails Ajax load record value on radio button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm struggling with the ajax part of my code. How to create a new entry or delete one is quite clear (thanks to codeschool), however in my case there is no submit on the form.

What I want - if someone clicks on a radio button showing the volume of a flash drive (1 gbyte, 2 gbyte, 4 gbyte) I want to display the price for the current flash drive size.

My records structure is following:
Product - contains general data
Options - contain price & volume

This is the part of my show.html.haml:

```
.col-sm-6
  .box
    %form
      .sizes
        %h3 Available sizes (Gbyte)
        -@volumes.each do |volume|
          -volume.each do |item|
            %label{:for => "size_#{item.id}"}
            %a{:href => "#", class: 'size_input'}
              =sprintf('%.0f', item.value/1000.to_f)
              GByte
            %input#size_s.size-input{:name => "volume", :type => "radio", :value => item.id}
      %p.price#priceValue
        =(@getCurrency[0].to_f).ceil
         USD
```

This is my products.coffee:

```
jQuery ->
    $('.size_input').on 'click', (event) ->
        selected_value = $('input[name=volume]:checked').val()
        $.ajax ->
            type: "GET"
            dataType: "json"
            url: "/products"
            success: (json) ->
                $('#priceValue').text(json.price)
```

I know the url is completely wrong in my ajax call, however my search efforts have not yielded any results so far.
Logically, I need to pass to the url my product id and retrieve the option, that matches "selected_value", but how do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the product id to the /products to get that specific product back.

```
url: '/products/' + selected_value
```

selected_value should be the id of the product.

In the controller you will need to use

```
product = Product.find(params[:id])
```

and return it as a json object.

```
render json: product
```

Comment: I might have been not specific enough - my prices are stored in the option record.
"selected_value" is the value, which I need to use for the option, not for the product.

I think I need to call something like this: products/135/options/1
And then retrieve the "price" of that record.

Comment: This is what I came up with so far:
    `$('.size_input').click (event) ->
        selected_value = $('input[name=volume]:checked').val()
        
        #console.log(url)
        $.ajax ->
            type: 'get'
            dataType: 'json'
            url: '/products/'
            data: { product: {option: {size: selected_value }}}
            success: (json) ->
                console.log(json)
                # $('#priceValue').text(json.price)`

Still receive some strange error msg:
No route matches [GET] "/products/function%20()%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%2... and so on

Comment: Add a route to your routes.rb file: get 'product/:pid/option/:oid' => "products#option" or a resource route.